Как правильно мокнуть коллекцию моделей laravel?
внутри аrtisan команды есть строка внутри конструктора
$this->transfers = TransferCrypto::where(["state" => 1])->with('ref_withdraw.user')->get();

как правильно её мокнуть в unit тесте без фабрик?
мой топорный вариант
    $mockQueryBuilder = Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder');
    $mockQueryBuilder
        ->shouldReceive('where')
        ->with(['state' => 1])
        ->once()
        ->andReturnSelf();
    $mockQueryBuilder
        ->shouldReceive('with')
        ->with('ref_withdraw.user')
        ->once()
        ->andReturnSelf();
    $mockQueryBuilder
        ->shouldReceive('get')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(collect([
            (object)[
                'id' => 1, 'state' => 1,
            ],
            (object)['id' => 2, 'state' => 1]
        ]));
    $mockTransferCrypto = Mockery::mock('overload:App\TransferCrypto'); // or 'alias'
    $mockTransferCrypto
        ->shouldReceive('where')
        ->with(['state' => 1])
        ->once()
        ->andReturn($mockQueryBuilder);

как правильно и красиво это зарефакторить?

Вопрос - а зачем это вообще нужно? Если цель куда-то вернуть коллекцию данных - так создайте её заранее и отсылайте..

это модульный тест, коллекции можно создать через фабрики, так в большинстве случаев и будет правильно, но иногда надо что то протестировать полностью изолировано

Так и тестируйте изолированно - создайте заранее объекты и отдавайте. Зачем что-то мокать? ...... цель у юнит-теста как правило протестировать поведение. Например engineStarted, для этого не надо проверять  есть ли на фабрике двигатели и привезти их с этой фабрики через службу логистики.... Ему надо просто сунуть двигатель и завести

покажите пример как в артисан команду прокинуть готовые коллекции, в этом и был вопрос

то есть отправная точка, например  Artisan::call('command:engineStarted')
а проверяем :
$this->assertEquals(3, $transfer->state);

В команду не надо ничего прокидывать. Подключаются либо фикстуры ( что-то типа такого: https://github.com/Corp-Soft/laravel-fixtures ), либо на крайняк прям в классе тестирования делается метод с данными, а средствами phpunit указывается аннотация @dataProvider для указания на этот метод с данными,... пример: https://dev.to/arielmejiadev/phpunit-dataprovider-with-laravel-9gg

ну так это же не изолировано получается, раз они все равно с базой взаимодействуют, не?)

Кто с базой взаимодействует? Модели заполняются заранее заданными данными из фикстур или из метода.

чем тогда глобально отличаются эти фикстуры от фабрик? если и те и другие "эмулируют" модели

в целом, я понял, спасибо за ссылки

Фабрика - это порождающий паттерн проектирования. Фикстура - это набор каких-либо данных. Т.е. вы сравниваете тёплое с мягким))  Если рассматривать их, то фабрика может использовать фикстуры для создания объекта.

Твой подход в целом верен, но его можно сделать более лаконичным и читаемым, убрав часть дублирующегося кода и улучшив структурированность. Вот пример рефакторинга:

Объедини мокирование вызовов where, with и get в одну последовательность.
Перемести мокирование метода where непосредственно на класс TransferCrypto.

Результат выглядит так:
// Мокируем запрос и его цепочку вызовов
$mockQueryBuilder = Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder')
    ->shouldReceive('with')
    ->with('ref_withdraw.user')
    ->andReturnSelf()
    ->getMock();

$mockQueryBuilder
    ->shouldReceive('get')
    ->andReturn(collect([
        (object)[ 'id' => 1, 'state' => 1 ],
        (object)[ 'id' => 2, 'state' => 1 ]
    ]));

// Мокируем класс TransferCrypto и метод where
$mockTransferCrypto = Mockery::mock('overload:App\TransferCrypto')
    ->shouldReceive('where')
    ->with(['state' => 1])
    ->andReturn($mockQueryBuilder)
    ->getMock();


Использование ->getMock(): помогает создать окончательный мок-объект без необходимости дополнительных вызовов.
Цепочка мокирования: в Mockery можно сразу комбинировать последовательные вызовы, чтобы сделать код компактнее.
Сокращение кода: определение и вызов with и get теперь находятся в одном блоке, что упрощает восприятие логики.

